# Alpine Linux (iSH) : ifquery: could not parse /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, networkmanager

I have iSH, which is actually a prooted(?) Alpine Linux on i(Pad)OS which works rather good with the `apk` package manager (not to be confused with Android APK), and network / internet connectivity is good as well.
But when I install Apache (version 2.4.56) I get these errors:

```
:~# rc-service apache2 start
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
 * Checking local filesystems  ...                                                                                                                                                       [ ok ]
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
 * Remounting filesystems ...                                                                                                                                                            [ ok ]
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
 * Mounting local filesystems ...                                                                                                                                                        [ ok ]
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
 * Starting networking ...
ifquery: could not parse /etc/network/interfaces
 * ERROR: networking failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start apache2 as networking would not start
```

The same occurs when I start `proftpd` while `sshd` runs normally:

```
~# rc-service proftpd start
grep: /proc/filesystems: No such file or directory
 * Starting networking ...
ifquery: could not parse /etc/network/interfaces
 * ERROR: networking failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start proftpd as networking would not start
```

It appears that a file is missing, but when I look at my Ubuntu in `/etc/networks`, then this file is missing as well, but Apache does not complain about this.

I tried starting networkmanager:

```
~# rc-service networkmanager start
 * rc-service: service `networkmanager' does not exist
```

Then I installed it `apk add networkmanager` but to no avail. Same issue.

Comment: iSH is a Linux shell for iOS phone/ipad, which is off-subject on this site.

Answer (score 0):

7

I was facing the same problem, you can start apache without using openrc.

Add RUN mkdir -p /run/apache2 to your Dockerfile, apache stores httpd.pid file in this directory. Finally start apache using : exec /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND

My Apache2 work!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).